# Page leaves white empty space when the page width decreases, why?

Tags: html, css

[this is the page] https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TjC4.png
After i made this page i noticed something's wrong with it when the page becomes smaller some unneccessary white space appears the page is split into three sections which i made them 100% width and 100vh (some of the sections dont have the same height) i have no idea what might be causing it.I use the inspect element to decrease the page width so i can watch how the page behaves when smaller width is applied, i dont know if i should include the css bc its like 400 lines and it probabily wont let me paste it all but if anyone has any idea what might be causing it please tell me.

```css
:root {
    --main-white: #f0f0f0;
    --main-red: #be3144;
    --main-blue: #45567d;
    --main-gray: #303841;
}

@media (max-width: 75em) {
    html {
      font-size: 60%;
    }
  }
  
  /* 980px / 16px = 61.25em */
  @media (max-width: 61.25em) {
    html {
      font-size: 58%;
    }
  }
  
  /* 460px / 16px = 28.75em */
  @media (max-width: 28.75em) {
    html {
      font-size: 55%;
    }
  }

  html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  
    /* Set font size for easy rem calculations
     * default document font size = 16px, 1rem = 16px, 100% = 16px
     * (100% / 16px) * 10 = 62.5%, 1rem = 10px, 62.5% = 10px
    */
    font-size: 62.5%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.8rem; /* 18px */
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: var(--main-white);
  }

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 9vh;
    background-color: var(--main-red);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}

#navbar ul {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

li {
    padding: 2rem;
    
}

#navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--main-white);
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
    background-color: var(--main-blue);
}

nav {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#welcome-section {
  background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #3a3d40 0%, #181719 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#welcome-section h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#welcome-section h2 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: var(--main-red);
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: italic;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #welcome-section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }

  header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 8vh;
  }

  #welcome-section h1 {
    font-size: 5.8rem;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }

  #welcome-section h2 {
    font-size: 2.8rem;
  }


  header li {
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding-top: 1.8rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.8rem;
  }
}

#projects {
  background-color: var(--main-blue);
  text-align: center;
  height: 145vh;
}

.project-tile {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.project-tile img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

#projects h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#projects h1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 68rem;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: var(--main-white);
}

h1, h2 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

p {
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: var(--main-gray);
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: var(--main-white);
  font-size: 2.2rem;
}

.project1, .project2, .project3, .project4{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

 #profile-link {
  background-color: var(--main-gray);
  color: var(--main-white);
  width: 150px;
  height: 45px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}


#profile-link:hover i {
  transform: translateX(5px);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#profile-link i {
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#profile-link:hover {
  background-color: var(--main-red);
  width: 170px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 2.3rem;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.code {
  color: var(--main-gray);
  transition: color 0.3s ease-out;
}

.project1:hover .code{
  color: #ff7f50;
}

.project3:hover .code{
  color: #ff7f50;
}

.project4:hover .code{
  color: #ff7f50;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {
  #projects {
    height: auto;
  }

  .project-tile {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 2rem;
  }

  .project-tile a {
    max-width: 400px;
  }

  .prj-img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }

  .prj-img2 {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }

  .caption {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .code {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  h1::after {
    border-bottom-width: 0.2rem;
  }
  
}
#description {
  background-color: var(--main-gray);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80vh;
}

#description h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
}

#description p {
  font-style: italic;
  margin-left: 100px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.square {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#description a {
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  color: var(--main-white);
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

#description a:hover {
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

.square .btn.contact-details {
  text-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.square .btn.contact-details i {
  text-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vh;
  background-color: var(--main-gray);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-top: 5px solid var(--main-red);
  align-items: center;
}

footer p, i.fab.fa-free-code-camp {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--main-white);
}

footer a {
  color:  var(--main-white);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
  section#description {
    text-align: center;
  }
  section#description p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    white-space: normal;
    margin: 0;
  }

  section#description h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
    white-space: normal;
  }

  div.square {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  footer p {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: normal;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 440px) {
  section#description h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <a href="#welcome-section"><li>About</li></a>
                <a href="#projects"><li>Work</li></a>
                <a href="#description"><li>Contact</li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="welcome-section">
        <h1>Hey I am Noel</h1>
        <h2>a web developer</h2>
    </section>
    <section id="projects">
        <h1>There are some of my projects</h1>
        <div class="project-tile">
            <a href="https://codepen.io/noelkasemi/pen/YzJqLKE" class="project1" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/tribute.jpg" alt="tribute page" class="prj-img">
                <p class="caption">
                    <span class="code"> < </span>
                    Tribute Page
                    <span class="code"> /> </span>
                </p>
            </a>
            <a href="https://codepen.io/noelkasemi/pen/oNaxdNw" class="project2" target="_blank">
                <img src="tchndp.png" alt="technical documentation page" class="prj-img2">
                <p class="caption">
                    <span class="code"> < </span>
                    Technical Documentation Page
                    <span class="code"> /> </span>
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="project-tile">
            <a href="https://codepen.io/noelkasemi/pen/wvYGjvQ" class="project3" target="_blank">
                <img src="lndp.png" alt="landing page" class="prj-img">
                <p class="caption">
                    <span class="code"> < </span>
                    Landing Page
                    <span class="code"> /> </span>
                </p>
            </a>
        
            <a href="https://codepen.io/noelkasemi/pen/ZEqWxgE" class="project4" target="_blank">
                <img src="srvf.png" alt="survery form" class="prj-img2">
                <p class="caption">
                    <span class="code"> < </span>
                    Survey Form
                    <span class="code"> /> </span>
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>
            <a href="https://codepen.io/your-work" id="profile-link" target="_blank">
                Show all
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>            
            </a>
        
    </section>
    <section id="description">
        <h1>Let's work together...</h1>
        <p>How do you take your coffee?</p>
        <div class="square">
        <a href="https://facebook.com/freecodecamp" target="_blank" class="btn contact-details"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i> Facebook</a>
        <a href="mailto:example@example.com" class="btn contact-details"><i class="fas fa-at"></i> Send a mail</a>
        <a href="tel:555-555-5555" class="btn contact-details"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i> Call me</a>
        <a class="profile-link" href="https://github.com/freecodecamp" target="_blank" class="btn contact-details"><i class="fab fa-github"></i> GitHub</a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/freecodecamp" target="_blank" class="btn contact-details"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
    </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>
            **This is just a fake portofolio.All the projects and contact details given are not real.
        </p>
        <p>
            © Created for
            <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/" target="_blank">freeCodeCamp <i class="fab fa-free-code-camp"></i></a>
          </p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I [copied all your code](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/wvYzvQp), made the page smaller, but I don't see any unnecessary white space appear? Can you explain your problem better?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware did you see my img i left , i dont excalty know how to explain it but when i made the page smaller the scroll bar appears at the bottom and if you scroll on it the white space appears as if my content doesnt fit the whole page also at the bottom the scroll bar appears as well in the left when you scroll to the end its just pure white space, oh i also used the inspect element maybe that did smth?

Comment: OK, yes, I get it now, and I can reproduce it.

Comment: I dug through your code, and I think it's the line underneath the title: _"There are some of my projects"_. If I remove that the white space doesn't show up anymore. It is the CSS rule `#projects h1::after`.

Comment: Not relevant to your problem, but you probably mean to say: _"Here are some of my projects"_.

Comment: Just for your better understanding try to inspect it in responsive mode and look for overflowing content, then  delete it to see if it removes the space.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thank you , it wasnt only that but in the 2nd section almost everything was too big for the page when it was decreased so it was spilling the content out , basically i used the wrong units i fixed it with media query, still thank you agian we beginners are such a mess

Answer (score 2):

This issue is always caused by some fixed width left somewhere deep in the code. Your case is no exception.

There is a fixed width set to an element which is also shifted around. It is found in the following part of your code:

```css
#projects h1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 68rem; // <<--- this line is causing the problem
  height: 2px;
  background-color: var(--main-white);
}
```

Comment: thanks the content on the 2nd section was just too big and spilled out , i used wrong units now i fixed it